# How to put skew overlay on a video

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a skew overlay on a video which is playing in the background with full width.

Currently the skew overlay is working perfectly but what if I want it on the right-bottom corner instead of top-left corner? Do I need to change the skew degree?

Here's my code:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #fff;
}

*,
*:after,
*:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

video {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  z-index: -100;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  background: url('//demosthenes.info/assets/images/container.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-transition: 1s opacity;
  transition: 1s opacity;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  padding: 5% 0 0 12%;
  letter-spacing: .1rem;
}

#container {
  height: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.overlay {
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.skew-overlay {
  z-index: 99;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -400px;
  width: 600px;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-transform: skewX(-45deg);
  transform: skewX(-45deg);
}

.content {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  width: 700px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.text {
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<video poster=".jpg" id="bgvid" playsinline autoplay muted loop>
<source src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/rain.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<div id="container">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="skew-overlay"></div>
    <div class="content">
      <span class="text">Wise busy past both park when an ye no. Nay likely her length sooner thrown sex lively income. The expense windows adapted sir. Wrong widen drawn ample eat off doors money. Offending belonging promotion provision an be oh consulted ourselves it. Blessing welcomed ladyship she met humoured sir breeding her. Six curiosity day assurance bed necessary. </br>Unpacked now declared put you confined daughter improved. Celebrated imprudence few interested especially reasonable off one. Wonder bed elinor family secure met. It want gave west into high no in. Depend repair met before man admire see and. An he observe be it covered delight hastily message. Margaret no ladyship endeavor ye to settling. </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the working fiddle- [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ocra7sj3/)

Comment: I want it exactly like it's on the top-left, but on the bottom-right

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I added an answer for you below

Answer (score 2):

From your comments on the question:

> I want the overlay exactly like it's on the top-left, but on the bottom-right

In this case simply change the `left` property in the CSS of `.skew-overlay` from `-400px` to `400px`:

```css
.skew-overlay {
  left: 400px;
  /* other rules here... */
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: #fff;
}

*,
*:after,
*:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

video {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  z-index: -100;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  background: url('//demosthenes.info/assets/images/container.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-transition: 1s opacity;
  transition: 1s opacity;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  padding: 5% 0 0 12%;
  letter-spacing: .1rem;
}

#container {
  height: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.overlay {
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.skew-overlay {
  z-index: 99;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 400px;
  width: 600px;
  background: #fff;
  -webkit-transform: skewX(-45deg);
  transform: skewX(-45deg);
}

.content {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
  width: 700px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.text {
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<video poster=".jpg" id="bgvid" playsinline autoplay muted loop>
<source src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/rain.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<div id="container">
  <div class="overlay">
    <div class="skew-overlay"></div>
    <div class="content">
      <span class="text">Wise busy past both park when an ye no. Nay likely her length sooner thrown sex lively income. The expense windows adapted sir. Wrong widen drawn ample eat off doors money. Offending belonging promotion provision an be oh consulted ourselves it. Blessing welcomed ladyship she met humoured sir breeding her. Six curiosity day assurance bed necessary. </br>Unpacked now declared put you confined daughter improved. Celebrated imprudence few interested especially reasonable off one. Wonder bed elinor family secure met. It want gave west into high no in. Depend repair met before man admire see and. An he observe be it covered delight hastily message. Margaret no ladyship endeavor ye to settling. </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I solve making this change on your Fiddle:

```css
.skew-overlay {
  z-index: 99;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: -200px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #ff0;
  -webkit-transform: skewX(-45deg);
  transform: skewX(-45deg);
}
```